# Can a single pointer point to multiple pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, unix

We could declare a pointer to an integer by writing int*. We already saw a pointer type char** argv. This is a pointer to pointers to characters.

Seems that argv is a pointer to multiple pointers which point to chars.

In C strings are represented by the pointer type char*. Under the hood they are stored as a list of characters, where the final character is a special character called the null terminator.

Is it the case with above char** where the pointers are stored as characters in the string ?

Comment: It is not fully clear what exactly it is you are asking.

Comment: totally unclear..

Comment: What is question?

Comment: the question is clear to me. dont know what else to say about it.

Comment: A pointer can point to an array of pointers. That's what `argv` does.

Comment: In `char **cptr`, it is *not* correct (even remotely) to say that "the pointers are stored as characters in the string".  `*cptr` is a pointer, and it points to an object of type `char`.  `cptr` is a pointer that points to a pointer, not a char.

Comment: Are you familiar with arrays?  Because you should be thinking in terms of arrays rather than strings, as a string is not really a thing that really exists in C so much as it is a `char` array that some functions treat in a special way to act like strings.  So it's not that you hold a string of pointers, but rather an array of pointers, much like how a string is in actuality an array of `char`s but with special significance to the null-terminator.

Comment: thank you @ChristianGibbons when i said 'string' i was thinking an array of char s

Answer (score 3):

A pointer can point to a single object, or it can point to an array of objects.

In the case of the `argv` parameter to `main` which is declared as `char *argv[]` (or equivalently `char **` since it is a function parameter), it is a pointer to an array of `char *`.

In memory it looks something like this:

```
argv
-----
| .-|---->  ------
-----       |    |       ----------------------------------
            |  .-|-----> | s | t | r | i | n | g | 1 | \0 |
            |    |       ----------------------------------
            ------
            |    |       ----------------------------------
            |  .-|-----> | s | t | r | i | n | g | 2 | \0 |
            |    |       ----------------------------------
            ------
            |    |       ----------------------------------
            |  .-|-----> | s | t | r | i | n | g | 3 | \0 |
            |    |       ----------------------------------
            ------
            ...
```

Answer (score 3):

When we define a `char *argv[]` for example :

**Example 1:**

```
char *p[5] = {{"ali"}, {"reza"}, {"hamid"}, {"saeed"}, {"mohsen"}};

for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    printf("%s\n", *p[i]);
```

**Example 2 :** (Here we have `5` pointers pointing to `char*`)

```
char **p;
p = new char*[5];

for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    p[i] = new char[10];
```

This happens in memory :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a reference to a memory address - pointer contains address to a variable. A pointer to pointer is a form of indirection where the pointer contains address to the other pointer variable. The second pointer variable contains address where the value is stored.

argv refers to argument vector which has reference to arguments passes to a program via the command line. As pointer argv refers to the first element in the character array; now since the vector is represented as an array its implicit to find the other pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A pointer `p` to type `T` can point to a single `T`, *or* to an array of `T`. In the latter case you can index into the array using pointer arithmetics, such as `p[n]`. In the same way, `argv[n]`'s pointees are not single `char`s, but nul-terminated arrays of `char`s, AKA C-style strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Memory-Address:  |0xA0|0xA1|0xA2|0xA3|0xA4|0xA5|0xA6|0xA7|
Memory-Content:  |        0x123      |       0x456       |
                 |-------4-Byte------|
                 |<- int* = 0x123
```

An pointer in C contains the address of a specific region in memory (ignoring VirtualMemory).
The pure address marks the start-position (here 0xA0) and the range is bounded by the size of the actual C-type.

But the content may be a pointer as well. (Here just 32-Bit addresses!)

```
Memory-Address:  |0xA0|0xA1|0xA2|0xA3|0xA4|0xA5|0xA6|0xA7|
Memory-Content:  |        0xA4       |        0x123      |
                 |-------4-Byte------|
                 |<- int** = 0xA4    |<- int* = 0x123
```

So you can construct any pointer hierarchy in memory.